# Django WSGI error

Tags: python, django, csrf, wsgi, web-deployment-project

I'm using Django for a per project. When I use an external API call in my views (function based view), I'm getting bad responses.

Here are my code snippits:

**views.py**

```
def stock_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StockForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            stock_ticker = form.cleaned_data["stock_ticker"]
            return render(request, 'article/stockinfo.html', get_search_query(stock_ticker),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = StockForm

    return render(request, 'article/index.html', {"form" : form })
```

.

```
def get_search_query(stock_ticker):
    print stock_ticker
    api = articleAPI('e4534187a7915ba69b41c1beab029d0f:8:71762357')
    articles = api.search(q = stock_ticker,
                          fq = {"news_desk" : "technology"},
                          fl = ["headline", "abstract", "pub_date", "news_desk", "_id"],
                          sort = "newest",
                          begin_date = str(20100101),
                          end_date = str(20150401),
                          )
    print articles

    return articles
```

It seems I'm getting some kind of bad response and it looks like a wsgi error. But If run the get_serach_query as a standalone code, it works. The get_search_query takes a stock ticker and retrieves results with New York Times Article API.

Comment: Do you have the actual error somewhere?

Comment: How are you running this? Using django's development server, or apache + mod_wsgi?

Comment: @Evert I'm running it using the Django development server.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I sent you the error message via email. Thank you !

Comment: Please add the error message to the question. There is no point to email me as nobody on StackOverflow can read my email.